# Open surfaces result coming from vector potential

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator

This is the last page of my Vector Calculus lecture notes:[image]

I've understood most of it I guess. The last equation basically is very similar to that of a conservative vector field, indeed we see that the integral around a closed surface (instead of a closed path) is $0$, and thus the integral is "surface-independent". However I don't understand if there is a mistake when it says

> where $s_1$ and $S_2$ are two open surfaces with the same boundary $C=\partial S_i$.

How come they are open? And also, shouldn't they be closed? It says that they have the same boundary, so I guess the boundary should indicate that they are closed curves?

Can you please help me clarify that last step/equation?

Thank you

Comment: "Closed surface" usually connotes a surface with no boundary (like a sphere or torus). "Open surface" is one that doesn't enclose a finite volume, because there's an "opening" for stuff to ooze out (like a hemisphere or paraboloid). By open surface the teacher means a bounded surface with a non-empty boundary curve. They're open in the sense I've said, not in any mathematical sense.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you! If you want to write it down more formally in an answer, I'll accept it!